# bash: using grep in if statement, prevent echo

Tags: bash, if-statement, grep

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

external_output="Oliver's AirPort Express"

if ~/.bin/audiodevice | grep "$external_output"
then
  ~/.bin/audiodevice output "Internal Speakers"
  echo "Internal Speakers"
else
  ~/.bin/audiodevice output "$external_output"
  echo "Oliver's AirPort Express"
fi
```

If the `grep` is matched, then it of course echoes the match. As I am using it in an if statement, I don't want this to echo.

How can I use `grep` in my `if` statement without having it announce the result to me when I run the script?

Comment: Best advice: RTFM. Seriously, the answer is RIGHT THERE in plain sight in the man page...

Comment: You're right. I didn't think the solution would be a flag for the `grep` command – I thought I might have to do something different with the `if` statement. So I was right to come here to ask for help, I wasn't just being ignorant… I was being more than that – dumb!

Comment: @EdMorton do you mean grep manual and an answer specific to grep? I have a similar problem with a different command, and I would like to know pure bash solution.

Comment: Yes. To be clear - grep is not bash. grep is a tool that can be called from bash. A pure bash solution to this question would involve a shell read loop and if you're considering that then see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)l. If in doubt, ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `grep -q "$external_output"` to suppress the output. From `man grep`:

> -q, --quiet, --silent
>
> Quiet; do not write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found,  even  if  an 
>   error  was
>             detected (-q is specified by POSIX).

Comment: I understand that this does answer the specific question, but I'd like to know a pure bash solution that doesn't rely on the command being so kind as to provide an option to silence it.

Comment: There is no generic solution to all possible problems you might be facing, you'd have to ask a question with a [mcve] for us to be able to help you with whatever it is you're trying to do.